# Update on hibernate and spring MVC not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am not able to update the table after editing it as it working fine when i debug and render all values in the DAO file but after dao implementation it is not showing the updated value for the same on user list. I am hereby attaching my code:

JSP File:

```
<form:form id="editForm" modelAttribute="user" action="update">
<div style="width: 400px; padding: 10px; border: 5px solid gray; margin: 0px;">
<table width="400px" height="150px">

<tr><td><font face="Arial">First Name:</font></td>
<td><input name="licenseNumber" value="${model.user.firstName}"></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Arial">Last Name:</font></td>
<td><input name="licenseNumber" value="${model.user.lastName}"></td></tr>

<tr><td><font face="Arial">Gender:</font></td>
<td><input name="licenseNumber" value="${model.user.gender}"></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="Arial">City Name:</font></td>
<td><input name="licenseNumber" value="${model.user.city}"></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td>
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
<br>
<a href="userList.html" >Cancel</a>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</form:form>
```

Dao method:

```
@Override
public void updateUser (User user)
{
    /*Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();*/

    sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().merge(user);
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) 
    {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUser() 
    {
        return userDao.getUser();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) 
    {
        return userDao.getUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user)
    {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView editUserData(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,  
   BindingResult result) {  
  Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
  model.put("user", userService.getUser(user.getId()));  
  return new ModelAndView("Edit","model",model);
 } 

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView updateUserData(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,  
   BindingResult result,SessionStatus status) {  
   userService.updateUser(user);
   status.setComplete();
   return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList.html");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. change **merge** by **update**

   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);
2. If 1 does not works try with:

   sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().merge(user);
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all your @Transactional methods as readOnly="true". You should override all methods which doing changes in databases.

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = false)
    public void addUser(User user) 
    {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUser() 
    {
        return userDao.getUser();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) 
    {
        return userDao.getUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = false)
    public void updateUser(User user)
    {
        userDao.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```